# Inspecting json structure

Tags: python, json, recursion

I am trying to print out a map of some json so I can quickly understand how it is structured. I have a function that recursively loops through nested json and prints all keys for items. However, it's not functioning quite like I expect. [example json](http://pastebin.com/mRtBjfM4)

```
def inspect_json(level,nested_json):
    for key in nested_json.keys():
        print "{}.{}".format(level,key)
        if isinstance(nested_json[key],dict):
            level += 1
            inspect_json(level,nested_json[key])

>>> inspect_json(1,data)
1.@xmlns:aws
1.aws:OperationRequest
2.aws:RequestId
2.aws:UrlInfoResult
3.aws:Alexa
4.aws:ContentData
5.aws:DataUrl
6.@type
etc...
```

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
>>> inspect_json(1,data)
aws:OperationRequest
  -aws:RequestId
aws:UrlInfoResult
  -aws:Alexa
    --aws:ContentData
    --aws:Related
    --aws:TrafficData
  -aws:ResponseStatus
    --@xmlns:aws
    --aws:StatusCode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
def inspect_json(level,nested_json):
    for key in nested_json.keys():
        print "{}.{}".format((level-1)*'  ',key)  # identation 2 blancs
        if isinstance(nested_json[key],dict):
            inspect_json(level+1,nested_json[key])  # increment level
```